# Converting switch to if-else to deal with "Constant expression required" in android

Tags: java, android

I noticed that I was getting the Constant expression required for my switch statement and so I tried converting the whole block of code (with ~40 statements) to an if-else using the android studio function and the error disappeared.

Is there any downside to doing this? Is there a specific reason that my switch statement throws that error and is it dangerous to just work around that issue with this solution?

Comment: can you share the error?

Comment: @PiyushMaheswari Oh it's just "error: constant string expression required" because for my case statements I use `public String a = Integer.toHexString(50);` declared in my MainActivity